# How to change dropdown option value with Document.execCommand()

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I am trying to pre-fill the values on the bigCommerce checkout page. As the checkout page uses embedded react, that's why I am unable to change the field values with plain javascript methods.
Although, I am able to change the values using Document.execCommand().
Here is the actual code for changing the first name:

> ```
>   document.getElementById("firstNameInput").focus();
>   document.execCommand("insertText", false, customerInfo.firstName);
> ```

But the problem is that I am unable to change/select country from the dropdown menu using Document.execCommand().

So my question is that, how can I change the dropdown value using document.execCommand?

**PS:** I know that document.execCommand is deprecated, but I don't have any alternate method available right now to change the values because as I said, plain javascript methods does not change the field values on bigcommerce checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had the same issue, and found this solution:

var sel=document.querySelector('#id-of-your-selector');
sel.options[1].selected=true; //option no to be select here I am selection the option at index no# 1, you can change
var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true }); //create his event
event.simulated=true; //add this too
sel.dispatchEvent(event);//dispatch event in this line sel is the element we created at first line for selector.
```